Photoshop javascript "rasterizePlaced" problem
I have a PS Javascript to combine two images from two folders. Everything works up until the second image is "placed" ("After placed"). The exception around the loop (below) trips on the "rasterizePlaced" line. If I open an image manually, then drop ("place") another image on top, I see that the Layer->Rasterize option in PS menu is grayed out. Is this the wrong way to "commit" a placed image? Win 10, PS 25.
            ...
            var doc = open(list1[i]);
            var docName = doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
            app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = folder1.displayName;
            alert("Placing file: "+list2[i]);
            placeFile(list2[i], 100);
            alert("After placed");
            app.runMenuItem(stringIDToTypeID('rasterizePlaced'));  // <- here
            alert("After runMenu");
            ...

